# How to Add Calculation in Field table using Hook Feathers?

Tags: node.js, hook, feathersjs

Suppose I have a table with three fields, "id", "firstValue", and "secondValue". I use postgres as its database. I want to add some calculation first, for example, the second field "firstValue" should be  ( firstValue + secondValue ) / 10. Does anyone know how to add this calculation in hooks service? Can someone give a method example in hooks?

This is a template in hooks service

```
module.exports = function () {
    return async context => {


      return context;
    };
  };
```

I save this file as calculate.js

And this is the template in hooks.js

```
let calculate = require('./../../hooks/calculate');

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [calculate()], // add some calculation  
    get: [calculate()], // add some calculation 
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`context.result` is the object that represents the result of the service call (mentioned here: https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/hooks.html), it can be accessed within after hooks. Then your hook should be:

```
module.exports = function () {
    return async context => {
        context.result.computedField = ( context.result.firstValue + context.result.secondValue ) / 10

      return context;
    };
};
```

And the hooks file should be:

```
let calculate = require('./../../hooks/calculate');

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [], 
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [calculate()],
    get: [calculate()],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },

  error: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  }
};
```